# Where is the TFS 2013-created Git repository located?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have created a new project via Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013 with a Git backend.  I am now curious as to where the central Git repository is located on disk.

I have searched for the project name in all directories on the TFS hosting server to no avail.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in TFS database like TFVC repositories. TFS speaks the [Git Transfer protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) over HTTP/S but internally the file are stored in tables'rows.

If you are curious about it, [TFS Internals - How does TFS store Git repositories?](http://www.richard-banks.org/2014/02/tfs-internals-how-does-tfs-store-git.html) drill down on implementation details. Caveat: the author is plain wrong on the role of _tfs_data directory. It is a cache to avoid expensive reconstruction of files from database rows. All user data is stored in TFS databases.

Comment: MS implement custom git object backend to store in SQL Server?

Comment: Why not? I added another link to my answer for details.